Consumer on azure bootsrap server and Producer on kafka bootstrapserver possible?
I have a consumer which consumes messages from azure eventhub, i am using spring cloud stream for binding and once messages are consumed i am using kafka producer too publish to a kafka topic. Now the issue is somehow, producer config is being picked as per azure eventhub and not per kafka and so it is not able to find the kafka topic in that bootstrap server and so it is failing. How to get it fixed where i want my consumer configuration to be as per azure event hub and producer config to be as per kafka. Following are my producer and consumer class and application yaml.
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class EventHubConsumer {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final CloudEventService cloudEventService;

    public EventHubConsumer(ObjectMapper objectMapper, CloudEventService cloudEventService) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.cloudEventService = cloudEventService;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> consume() {
        return message->{
            Checkpointer checkpointer = (Checkpointer) message.getHeaders().get(CHECKPOINTER);
            log.info("New message received: '{}', partition key: {}, sequence number: {}, offset: {}, enqueued "
                            +"time: {}",
                    message.getPayload(),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubsHeaders.PARTITION_KEY),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubsHeaders.SEQUENCE_NUMBER),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubsHeaders.OFFSET),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubsHeaders.ENQUEUED_TIME)
            );
            try{
//                // Replace single quotes with double quotes
                String payload = message.getPayload().replaceAll("'", "\"");
                CloudEvent cloudEvent = objectMapper.readValue(payload, CloudEvent.class);
                cloudEventService.processEvents(cloudEvent)
                        .doOnSuccess(success -> {
                            log.info("Message '{}' successfully processed", message.getPayload());
                            checkpointer.success().subscribe();
                        })
                        .doOnError(error -> {
                            log.error("Failed to process message '{}'", message.getPayload(), error);
                        })
                        .subscribe();

            }catch (Exception e){
                log.error("Error occurred while processing message", e);
            }
        };
    }
}

and following is producer class which is being called from consumer
@Service
public class DefaultCloudEventService implements CloudEventService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultCloudEventService.class);
    private final ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;

    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    private final Mapper<CloudEvent, AvroCloudEvent> mycloudEventMapper;

    DefaultCloudEventService(ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate, AppConfig appConfig, Mapper<CloudEvent, AvroCloudEvent> myCloudEventMapper) {
        this.reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate = reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
        this.mycloudEventMapper = mycloudEventMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> processEvents(CloudEvent event) {
        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> this.processEvent(event));
    }

    public void processEvent(CloudEvent microsoftCloudEvent) {
        String topic = getTopic();
        String errorTopic = getErrorTopic();
        reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send(topic, "someId", "Message to be published")
                .doOnSuccess(senderResult -> log.info("Successfully sent message. topic={}", topic))
                .doOnError(e -> {
                    log.error("Error occurred sending kafka message.  message={}, cause={}", e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
                    log.error("Failed to send message.  message={}, topic={}", microsoftCloudEvent, topic, e);
                    reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send(errorTopic, "someId", "Message to be published")
                            .subscribe();
                    log.error("publishing to error topic.  topic={}", errorTopic);
                })
                .subscribe();
    }
}

And following is application.yaml file
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhubs:
        enabled: true
        connection-string: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_PASSWORD:Endpoint=sb://test-ehub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test-ehubns-sub;SharedAccessKey=cuPsy/qTevnSP82/ztE=;EntityPath=}
        namespace: test-ehub-namespace
        client:
          transport-type: AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS
        processor:
          checkpoint-store:
            account-name: testaccount
            container-name: testContainer
            sas-token: ?test-token%3D}
    function:
      definition: consume
    stream:
      poller:
        initial-delay: 0
        fixed-delay: 1000
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          destination: test-event-hub
          group: test-eventhub-consumer
      eventhubs:
        bindings:
          consume-in-0:
            consumer:
              checkpoint:
                mode: MANUAL
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:test-boostrstrapserver}
    security:
      protocol: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL:SSL}
    ssl:
      key-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD}
      key-store-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_KEY_STORE_LOCATION:file:src/main/resources/certs/keystore.jks}
      key-store-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
      trust-store-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_TRUST_STORE_LOCATION:file:src/main/resources/certs/truststore.jks}
      trust-store-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
      protocol: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_PROTOCOL:SSL}
    producer:
      acks: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_ACKS:all}
      compression-type: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_COMPRESSION_TYPE:snappy}
      retries: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_RETRIES:100}
      batch-size: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_BATCH_SIZE:100}
      key-serializer: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_KEY_SERIALIZER:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer}
      value-serializer: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_VALUE_SERIALIZER:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer}
      properties:
        delivery.timeout.ms: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS:400000}
        request.timeout.ms: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS:350000}
        schema.registry.url: ${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
        specific.avro.reader: true

com:
  abc:
    swf:
      config:
        kafka-topic-name: kafka-input-topic
        kafka-error-topic-name: kafka-error-topic

I tried adding kafka binding for producer , and this is the application.yaml file after that change
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhubs:
        enabled: true
        connection-string: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_PASSWORD:Endpoint=sb://test-ehub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test-ehubns-sub;SharedAccessKey=cuPsy/qTevnSP82/ztE=;EntityPath=}
        namespace: test-ehub-namespace
        client:
          transport-type: AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS
        processor:
          checkpoint-store:
            account-name: testaccount
            container-name: testContainer
            sas-token: ?test-token%3D}
    function:
      definition: consume
    stream:
      poller:
        initial-delay: 0
        fixed-delay: 1000
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          destination: test-event-hub
          group: test-eventhub-consumer
      eventhubs:
        bindings:
          consume-in-0:
            consumer:
              checkpoint:
                mode: MANUAL
      kafka:
        bindings:
          output: # This is for the Kafka producer
            destination: kafka-input-topic
            group: kafkaProducerGroup  # use a different consumer group for Kafka
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:test-boostrstrapserver}
    security:
      protocol: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL:SSL}
    ssl:
      key-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD}
      key-store-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_KEY_STORE_LOCATION:file:src/main/resources/certs/keystore.jks}
      key-store-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
      trust-store-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_TRUST_STORE_LOCATION:file:src/main/resources/certs/truststore.jks}
      trust-store-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
      protocol: ${SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_PROTOCOL:SSL}
    producer:
      acks: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_ACKS:all}
      compression-type: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_COMPRESSION_TYPE:snappy}
      retries: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_RETRIES:100}
      batch-size: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_BATCH_SIZE:100}
      key-serializer: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_KEY_SERIALIZER:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer}
      value-serializer: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_VALUE_SERIALIZER:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer}
      properties:
        delivery.timeout.ms: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS:400000}
        request.timeout.ms: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS:350000}
        schema.registry.url: ${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
        specific.avro.reader: true

com:
  abc:
    swf:
      config:
        kafka-topic-name: kafka-input-topic
        kafka-error-topic-name: kafka-error-topic

But still producer config is being picked as per azure eventhub and not as per kafka. Following is the error message
ERROR DefaultCloudEventService.lambda$processEvent$2 - Failed to send message.  message=com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.implementation.models.CloudEvent@1b0a90e4, topic=kafka-input-topic
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic ekafka-input-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Following is the producer config being generated which is as per kafka and not as per azure(which is desirable)
INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.ProducerConfig.logAll - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    batch.size = 100
    bootstrap.servers = [test-ehub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093]
    ssl.keystore.location = /src/main/resources/certs/keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = SSL
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = src/main/resources/certs/truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

I have removed many config values from above and also many packages and codes from above due to compliance issue. Please help me how to fix this issue? and get consumer and producer working on different messaging system

You can achieve this by adding the Kafka producer configuration in the application.yaml file. You can add the following configuration in your application.yaml file to use Kafka producer configuration:
spring:
cloud:
stream:
kafka:
binder:
brokers: :
